# MS Edge and Internet explorer open nav links on hover without clicking it

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, microsoft-edge, wp-nav-walker

A customer reported that the some links on his Wordpress website are being opened when hovered over it. This only occurres on MS Browsers like Edge (Version 14 to 18) and IE. 
The theme was not done by me, but by some other dev around 1 year ago and he used the bootstrap-nav-walker for generating the header menu and all hrefs generated by it show this strange behaviour

I tried on different devices running different versions of Edge and IE and the problem stays. 
There is only the bootstrap 3 methods triggered when hovering over the items, which works on other sites just fine.
Customer also said this problem occurred when the site launched roughly 1 1/2 yrs ago and was fixed by some JS code, but couldn't tell me what exactly had been done.

This is the Code used for generating the Menuitems:

```php
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
   <?php

      $bs4navwalker = new bs4navwalker();

       wp_nav_menu([
           'menu'            => 'main',
           'theme_location'  => 'main',
           'container'       => false,
           'menu_id'         => false,
           'menu_class'      => 'navbar-nav',
           'depth'           => 0,
           'fallback_cb'     => 'bs4navwalker::fallback',
           'walker'          => $bs4navwalker
       ]);

   ?>
</div>
```

and this is the result

```html
<ul id="menu-hauptnavigation" class="navbar-nav">
    <li id="menu-item-155" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-155 nav-item dropdown">
        <a href="/unternehmen/erfolgsmodell-customer/" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Unternehmen</a>      <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a href="https://www.customer.ag/erfolgsmodell-customer/" class=" dropdown-item">Erfolgsmodell customer</a>
            <a href="https://www.customer.ag/erfolgsmodell-systempartnerschaft/" class=" dropdown-item">Erfolgsmodell Systempartnerschaft</a>
            <a href="https://www.customer.ag/systemzentrale/" class=" dropdown-item">Systemzentrale</a>
            <a href="https://www.customer.ag/werte-ambitionen/" class=" dropdown-item">Werte &amp; Ambitionen</a>
            <a href="https://www.customer.ag/zahlen-fakten/" class=" dropdown-item">Zahlen &amp; Fakten</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-3042" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-3042 nav-item dropdown">
        <a href="https://www.customer.ag/systempartner-werden/" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Systempartner werden</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">

            <a href="https://www.customer.ag/systempartner-werden/" class=" dropdown-item">Systempartner werden</a>
            <a href="https://www.customer.ag/gruenderkategorien/gruenderstories/" class=" dropdown-item">Gründerstories</a>
            <a href="https://www.customer.ag/apotheke-gruenden-2/" class=" dropdown-item">Apotheke gründen</a>
            <a href="https://www.customer.ag/filialisieren/" class=" dropdown-item">Filialisieren</a>
            <a href="https://www.customer.ag/umziehen-2/" class=" dropdown-item">Umbauen / Umziehen</a>
            <a href="https://www.customer.ag/customermodul/" class=" dropdown-item">customer Modul</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-224" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-224 nav-item dropdown">
        <a href="https://www.customer.ag/standort-anbieten/" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Standort anbieten</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">

            <a href="https://www.customer.ag/standort-anbieten/" class=" dropdown-item">Standort anbieten</a>
            <a href="https://www.customer.ag/standort-anbieten/fachmarktzentren/" class=" dropdown-item">Fachmarktzentren</a>
            <a href="https://www.customer.ag/standort-anbieten/innenstadtlagen/" class=" dropdown-item">Innenstadtlagen</a>
            <a href="https://www.customer.ag/standort-anbieten/fussgaengerzonen/" class=" dropdown-item">Fußgängerzonen</a>
            <a href="https://www.customer.ag/standort-anbieten/vorkassenzonen/" class=" dropdown-item">Vorkassenzonen</a>
            <a href="https://www.customer.ag/standort-anbieten/bahnhof-flughafen/" class=" dropdown-item">Bahnhöfe / Flughäfen</a>
            <a href="https://www.customer.ag/standort-anbieten/shopping-malls/" class=" dropdown-item">Shopping Malls</a>
            <a href="https://www.customer.ag/standort-anbieten/parkplaetze-grundstuecke-fuer-modul/" class=" dropdown-item">Parkplätze / Grundstücke für Modul</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-4155" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4155 nav-item">
        <a href="https://www.customer.ag/karriere/" class="nav-link">Karriere</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

We use the BSNavwalker on different wordpress sites as well and none shows this strange behaviour. Also I couldn't find any help regarding Edge or IE opening links on hover.

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem on my side, it seems that the result works well. perhaps some customer using JavaScript code to add the hover event and will click the button in the hover event. You could suggest them to check it.

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT problem occurs on my side as well, not only on the customers side.
I am currently checking all JS events, which are triggered